# Is there a way to include your Patreon page when the credit rolls after a movie?

Tags: formatting

Is there a way to include your Patreon page when the credit rolls after a movie?

Me and some friend are going to release a short movie and we want to add a Patreon page during the credits, is there a way to do it? What is the usual written format?

Answer (score 1):

Patreon-funded films are a bit of a new thing, compared to the film industry as a whole, so there is no "traditional" format. Here are some options that might work:

- Show a URL for the film's website.

  - Pros: Audience members only need to remember one piece of information, and that information is probably more memorable. You can design the site however you like, and include whatever links you want, including a link to the Patreon.
  - Cons: Now you have to set up a website, a domain name, etc. and maintain all of those things indefinitely.
- Show an image of the Patreon logo followed by your Patreon username.

  - Pros: Still memorable, looks reasonably neat.
  - Cons: Are you going to do the same for all of your other social media? Then it will get cluttered and ugly. Also, some people won't know what a "Patreon" is and will be confused by the logo.
- Show the URL of your Patreon page.

  - Pros: More accessible to people who are unfamiliar with Patreon.
  - Cons: The URL will be longer and uglier compared to other options. Viewers may not remember the whole thing.

Whatever option you choose, this sort of administrivia normally appears at or very close to the end of the credits, after the cast, crew, and special thanks (if any). Normally, you don't give a website priority over a human; depending on how the film was produced, you may be contractually obligated to put such information at or near the end (because a cast or crew member's contract may require specific ordering and placement). However, if your film was produced informally (and you didn't sign a document [like this one](https://www.sagaftra.org/files/short_film_agreement_1_13_0.pdf)), then such legalities may not be applicable to you.